# Splitting git history into branches

Tags: git, split, branch, revision-history

We use Git for out repo. I've no idea how but my team's latest history ended up like this:

```
0                 master
 \
  1-2-3-4-5-6-7   branch1 & branch2
```

Notice how (thankfully) nobody has merged this with our master branch yet. Now, I want to split that to end up like this:

```
             5-6-7     branch2
            /     \
0  - - -  (*) - - (*)  master
 \       /  
  1-2-3-4              branch1
```

I'm not experienced with Git and I'd like to know how to achieve that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming both `branch1` and `branch2` are pointing at 7, the safer option is to create another branch `n_branch1` and do the following:

```
git checkout <sha_4>
# you'll now be in a detached head
git checkout -b n_branch1   
# Now go to master and merge n_branch1
git checkout master
git merge n_branch1
# Once branch1 commits are merged, apply branch2 on top of them.
git checkout branch2
git rebase master
```

Note: You could also reuse `branch1` by reverting it to 4 (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)).

Comment: I ended up going with your 2nd idea of reusing branch1 by reverting to 4. Thanks!